# could not drop oracle view because view does not exist but the view still there

Tags: sql, oracle, view, ddl

So I am trying to drop a view... but it says it doesn't exist but I can still look at it and describe it, how could it happen?

http://i58.tinypic.com/23upo37.png

Sorry but I cant post image yet.

Comment: Sorry, my proxy doesnt support this link. You tried prefixing with schema name?

Comment: I did try that as well

Comment: Instead of posting pictures, just copy and paste the **text**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the screen you provided I realized that you are trying to drop the  USER_CONS_COLUMNS view. USER_CONS_COLUMNS is a system view you can't drop it.

Comment: Um, not quite right.  You can drop this view if you really want to.

Comment: I expressed not very well, I was going to say that the author of the question must not drop this view, because of the future problems with the database. But thank you anyway for such a good point.

Answer (score 0):

`USER_CONS_COLUMNS` is a public synonym for a data-dictionary view with the same name.  You are getting an error because you are trying to use `DROP VIEW` to drop a public synonym:

```
SQL> create view test_view as select * from dual;

View created.

SQL> create public synonym test_view_syn for test_view;

Synonym created.

SQL> desc test_view_syn;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DUMMY                                              VARCHAR2(1)

SQL> drop view test_view_syn;
drop view test_view_syn
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

If you really want to, you can drop the public synonym `USER_CONS_COLUMNS`:

```
SQL> drop public synonym user_cons_columns;

Synonym dropped.
```

And then it appears to have gone, for all users other than `SYS`:

```
SQL> desc user_cons_columns
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object user_cons_columns does not exist
```

Getting it back is fairly easy.  Run this as `SYS`:

```
SQL> create public synonym user_cons_columns for sys.user_cons_columns;

Synonym created.
```

But why on earth do you want to drop this view?

Comment: I have been trying to generate an EF for my project, always get the errors about some system views have error.. I couldn't see a way to fix them to get the model generated...

Comment: @NoobieCoder: I think it would be better for you to ask a question about how to fix the errors you mention (and *please* include the actual errors in the question).  Perhaps someone would be able to see a way to fix them.  Dropping parts of Oracle is never a good idea, as other applications you may wish to use with your Oracle database may assume that they exist.

Comment: To be honest, the Entity Framework has so much blackbox stuffs inside of it. The problem plagues me sometimes point me to the mapping issue, on other times, it point to the Oracle view errors... That is why I was trying to drop them but look like it wasn't Oracle.